# Configure VS2013 help language

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have installed VS2013 in german. However, I find that the german documentation is sometimes lacking and generally I prefer the english one. (The automated translation has come far, but I am used to the english terms)

When I select StringBuilder and press F1, i am consistently directed towards [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=DE-DE&k=k%28System.Text.StringBuilder%29;k%28StringBuilder%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework). I'd like to see [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

I have searched the settings menu, but I only found the general language setting and the option online help vs. local help. I don't want to download the documentation, I want the online help.

Additionally, I have picked english (us) in the msdn language picker and reordered the "preferred languages" in firefox to read "en-us", "en", "de". Which results in this header:

```
Accept Language en-us,en;q=0.7,de;q=0.3
```

Still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be there (at least it was there some day). See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zzt41xa%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> **Online topic language**
>
> Specifies the language in which to search and display results for online Help sources only.
>
> The available languages depend on the Help source. For example, MSDN Online supports multiple languages, but some Codezone Community sites might not support any language other than English.

It seems this was deprecated in Visual Studio 2010. There is a [page however on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/selectlocale-dmc) itself to change the preferred language.

**Conclusion:**

Even after changing the language to German (in my case English was default) and clicking <kbd>F1</kbd>, the language did not change. I suggest to create an issue at [connect.microsoft.com](http://connect.microsoft.com).

Comment: Indeed, I can't find the setting in VS2013. The msdn language picker is not working for the online help.

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster: you are right. I tried it myself, without luck :( . Suggest to add an issue at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster: Did you create a bug report? Can you post the link, I will give it a vote.

Comment: I finally got to it. Here is the link: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/846567/language-preference-of-documentation-is-not-adjustable